# how to show fixed scrollbar in listview if there is no items present in listview

Tags: android, xml, listview

I ve got a listview need to show the fixed scrollbar in listview even if there is no items present in the listview . i tried these attributes `android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"` still i m not getting the fixed scroll bar..am m making mistake some where..below is the code.

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@drawable/scrollbar"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scroll"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />
```

Comment: can u set minimum height parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Try this attribite  `android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack= "true"` may help you